# Why am I getting Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I would like to have the rows that are not being displayed but get an error subquery returns more than 1 row

This works fine;

```
SELECT CONCAT( P.LastName, ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name, 
(
SELECT MP.MembershipID
FROM membershipperson MP
WHERE MP.PersonID = P.PersonID
) 
AS MembershipID, PersonID
FROM `person` P
```

This fails when I add the ORDER BY 'MembershipID' it works if I ORDER BY 'PersonID';

```
SELECT CONCAT( P.LastName, ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name, 
(
SELECT MP.MembershipID
FROM membershipperson MP
WHERE MP.PersonID = P.PersonID
) 
AS MembershipID, PersonID
FROM `person` P
ORDER BY `MembershipID` ASC
```

How do I get the list with all the MembershipID rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it important to use a subquery? You might write it using `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( P.LastName, ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name,
    MP.MembershipID,
    P.PersonID
FROM `person` P
INNER JOIN `membershipperson` MP ON MP.PersonID = P.PersonID
ORDER BY MP.MembershipID ASC
```

Comment: Whith this I also get the PersonID in field list is ambigous

Comment: @user3066675 - Are you sure you copied the query correctly? Every column is being qualified in this query with the table alias.

Comment: Your right I missed something it appears to give me what I'm I looking for now... THANK YOU

Comment: I edited the SQL a few seconds after posting it, SO should have shown it anyway. Probably like José too, I first copied `PersonID` without qualifying it.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use an inner join. Something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT( P.LastName, ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name, MP.MembershipID AS MembershipID, PersonID
FROM person P, membershipperson MP
WHERE MP.PersonID = P.PersonID
```

Comment: I don't see the INNER JOIN there. Whith this I get; Column 'PersonID' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: The inner join is implicit. If you want it explicitly:

Comment: SELECT CONCAT( P.LastName, ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name, MP.MembershipID AS MembershipID, PersonID
FROM person P INNER JOIN membershipperson MP ON MP.PersonID = P.PersonID

Comment: I get a major failure with this. If you like I can share it with you but the message is very long.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake with your code. But still get this message... Column 'PersonID' in field list is ambiguous.  I am new to this so please be patient with me. THANKS!

Comment: I think your asking how I manage the db. I am in the database portal using phpMyAdmin on the host server.

Comment: Yeah, I see why you get that, just add P. to the PersonID on the field list. Like this: SELECT CONCAT( P.LastName, ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name, MP.MembershipID AS MembershipID, P.PersonID ....

Comment: José, This also worked, more than one way to skin a cat. I get the same list as the code that Stephan offered. Thanks to you both.       Bob